# Kentico cms.file publish date

Tags: kentico

I've got a simple repeater that list links to uploaded documents using cms.file. I'm drawing a blank on adjust the ORDER BY based on publish date. I can't find anything here on this, so i apologize if this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

Best practice is to add custom field to page type (in this case cms.file or better create the new one) and set ORDER BY condition to this new field. There are also properties like DocumentModifiedWhen, DocumentCreatedWhen, DocumentCheckedOutWhen you can use.

Comment: I've thought about this. Actually, i'm still considering adding a new field to cms.file page type.

Comment: IMHO it`s pretty cheap to add new field (even with default value) and you have full control over all possible values (in scope of your ORDER BY condition). I think this is the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to use DocumentModifiedWhen as the ORDER By statement.

Answer (score 0):

There are two fields `[DocumentPublishTo]` and `[DocumentPublishFrom]` that you can think of using. These are the two fields which appear at the bottom of each form page by default.

Comment: These aren't being used in this case.

Comment: I thought you were talking about published date with in Kentico. You best bet in this case would be to create a field in the page type of date time and use that fields to order your documents.